# send ICMP packet to an fixed ip address all the time

Tags: sockets, icmp

When I run Wireshark to see what is HTTP redirect packet like, I find my computer send ICMP packet to an fixed IP address all the time. My computer run windows 10 operation system, more detail about this packet see this:

[image: this]

How can I find which process send these ICMP packet?

Comment: Have you tried blocking the destination address in your firewall and seeing which process throws an error or crashes?  Failing that its a process of elimination, stop one process at a time until you find the right one.

Comment: @CodeGorilla I will try to block any packet to that dest ip address and see whether there is an application to show me a notice.I am doing as what you say "stop one process at a time until you find the right one"